# How to write FOR loop in Python Impala?

Tags: python, sql, hive, impala

I am trying to write a script to list all tables in all databases in impala using python. I am getting stuck at for loop section.

```
for i in databases.db:
    cur.execute("show tables in", &i)   #error occurs here
    output11 = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
    print(output11)
```

Since impala syntax is SHOW TABLES IN DATABASE_NAME
The issue is same for HIVE.

Comment: aren't you missing the `?` in the execute string?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in databases.db:
    q1="show tables in "
    q2=q1+i
    cur.execute(q2)  #error occurs here
    output11 = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
```

I found the answer. Thanks for viewing.